# Measure of difference between two N-dimensional bases

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

I have an $N$-dimensional space $\Bbb{R}^N$. I have a basis $B$ in $\Bbb{R}^N$, made up of $N$ $N$-vectors of unit length. I have another basis $C$ in the same space. I want to measure how "different" $B$ and $C$ are in some way. I put that in quotes because I'm not sure how that should be defined, so I'm open to ideas.

I've been trying to use the amount of rotation. I can picture it in 2 or 3 dimensions, as a single rotation on a unique plane of rotation. When $N>3$, there are $\lfloor{N/2}\rfloor$ planes of rotation and their associated angles of rotation required to describe the rotation, and my ability to visualize is gone.

If I could take my bases, and calculate their planes and angles of rotation, I would probably be happy. I could somehow combine the $\lfloor{N/2}\rfloor$ angles of rotation to arrive at some summary number of different-ness (details TBD). But:

- a) I haven't been able to find a method to determine the planes/angles of rotation from actual values in many dimensions, just that it is theoretically possible.
- b) There might be a better way to measure "different".

If it helps, my bases are eigenvectors of covariances of two noisy samples of $N$-dimensional data. My application has $N$ between 5 and 30, give or take.

To show I'm trying, so far I've found the pairwise angles between all the vectors in the two bases. I can then use the Hungarian/Munkres algorithm to find the best pairings of vectors in the two bases such that the sum of the angles between the pairs is minimized. I consider this to have ordered the vectors so that the $i$th vector in $B$ is best matched to the $i$th vector in $C$ (I believe these are called a frames, rather than bases, once ordered). I feel this is progress. But it leaves me with $N$ angles, when I know that this is theoretically representable by $\lfloor{N/2}\rfloor$ angles. There must be redundant information in there. Or I might be totally on the wrong track.

I've gotten this far using wikipedia. My math training is zilch. Please be gentle.

Comment: You can't in general assume that two bases are related by a rotation. However, if the two bases are expressed in terms of another single basis, then you can define the transformation between the two bases, and you can look for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of that transformation.

Comment: @Muphrid I was surprised that bases aren't always rotations of one another (did I mention no math training?), but further research tells me you are right. In my case, as the bases are eigenvectors, they are orthonormal. That ought to mean they are always rotations of each other... right? I'm working on the rest of the problem still, including using hints/leads in your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Even in that case, the two bases need not be rotated compared to each other. One could be a reflection of the other. The good news is that, because the two bases are orthonormal, the transformation between them is guaranteed to be some number of reflections (a rotation is just two reflections). This is called an orthogonal transformation.